# SSH key login refused

Tags: ssh

I am trying to log-in using my public key. I can do it for root user but not for any non-privileged user.

I tried giving permissions on the user .ssh directory (700 for the directory and 600 for the authorized_keys) but no success at all. I copied the authorized_keys file from the root folder to the user folder

Each time I try to log-in I get this message (from PuTTY)

> Disconnected. No supported authentication methods available (server
>   sent: publickey)

However with root it works fine I get asked my passphrase and I get in normally...

I also tried creating a folder inside /etc/ssh with the username and copying the authorized_keys file but no success either

Comment: the error message suggests that you don't provide any key file in putty. check your putty configuration (`Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Private key file...`).

Comment: I do provide the file. it works with root. I use the same settings for both users

Comment: if you didn't modify the PuTTYgen key prior to pasting it, check out this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204400/ssh-public-key-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publ

Comment: Is the owner of the `authorized_keys` files the login name that you are using? And is the owner of `.ssh` that one too?

Comment: Well there is no owner for the key I guess. The key is valid using SSH2-RSA I made a new pair and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your public key has to be located at the path you set in your config.
In my case it would be:

```
/home/$USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

My config (only relevant part):

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentification no
```

Check the value of ***AuthorizedKeysFile*** in your config and locate your public key there or change it to the given example.

Comment: /home/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys exists and the config file is also set-up like yours

Comment: Did you generate a new pair of keys?

Comment: I did not. I just used PuTTY gen and pasted the public key into the authorized_keys file

Comment: Generate a new pair and try again.